# Tutorial example of while loop not working for me

Tags: mysql, sql, while-loop

Im trying an example while loop from this [link](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/loops/for_loop.php)

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

WHILE @cnt < 10
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Inside simulated FOR LOOP on TechOnTheNet.com';
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;

PRINT 'Done simulated FOR LOOP on TechOnTheNet.com';
GO
```

But then Im getting these errors :-

```
mysql> DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @cnt INT = 0' at line 1

```
mysql> 
mysql> WHILE @cnt < 10
    -> BEGIN
    ->    PRINT 'Inside simulated FOR LOOP on TechOnTheNet.com';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHILE @cnt < 10
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Inside simulated FOR LOOP on TechOnTheNet.com'' at line 1


mysql>    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> END;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1


mysql> 
mysql> PRINT 'Done simulated FOR LOOP on TechOnTheNet.com';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PRINT 'Done simulated FOR LOOP on TechOnTheNet.com'' at line 1
mysql> GO
ERROR: 
No query specified
```

Comment: You can only execute this code from a stored procedure, not from the MySQL command line.  And, in general, you should avoid using explicit loops in MySQL, as SQL databases are set-based tools which implicitly loop over tables already.

Comment: Is there any way toe execute a while loop from MYSQL cli ?

Comment: Its SQL Server tutorial and you are trying it on MySQL.

Comment: Not of which I'm aware, but then again why do you want to do this?

Comment: actually Ive a table with a certain column (float values). And for each of the row of this column I want to create another column with row value=(old_value*3.5 +78)

Comment: Search for MySQL tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You're copying from a SQL server tutorial while using MySQL.

The correct version in MySQL is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test() 
BEGIN   
  DECLARE cnt INT DEFAULT 0;

  WHILE cnt < 10 DO
    SELECT 'Inside simulated FOR LOOP on TechOnTheNet.com';
    SET cnt = cnt + 1;
  END WHILE;
END//
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4fb7c/1.

Comment: mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test() 
    -> BEGIN   
    ->   DECLARE cnt INT DEFAULT 0;                  
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

Comment: Can you try without CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test() BEGIN, and the last END?

Comment: mysql> BEGIN   
    ->   DECLARE cnt INT DEFAULT 0;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE cnt INT DEFAULT 0' at line 2

Comment: You need to connect to a database first. Could you try following https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/connect-to-mysql-from-the-command-line?

Comment: connected to a test DB and again got this error for the very first line. mysql> DECLARE cnt INT DEFAULT 0;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE cnt INT DEFAULT 0' at line 1

Comment: After you connect to a test DB, you need the `CREATE PROCEDURE` version.